# Mutex class member

Tags: c++, multithreading

If I have a class with 5 member variables, e.g.,

```
class XYZ
{
public:
double x1;
......
double x5;
};
```

There are 5 threads which each one of them access 1 member variable of the same object (which one is unknown). If I want to make it thread-safe and also efficient, is it necessary to create 5 mutex member in the class as well. In other words,

```
class XYZ
{
public:
double x1;
......
double x5;
boost::mutex mutex1;
......
boost::mutex mutex5;
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could perhaps use `std::atomic<double>` and not do any manual synchronization, if that's an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A mutex can be locked and unlocked from the same thread, so if you have 5 different threads which will acquire 5 different critical sections at the same time, Yes you will need separate mutex for each of them.

Comment: thank you for your reply. Is this a good multithreading design? I mean having 1 mutex for each object member inside the class.

Comment: @2607: I guess you realize it's not a very elegant design but it will get the job done. It is difficult to say how you can avoid it unless the requirements and the approach of your implementation is fully known.

Comment: The example is over simplified, actually this is what I am trying to achieve. I have a vector of M objects, and each object has N member variables. There are X threads and each one may access any member variables of any object inside the vector. I am trying to achieve this and also having minimum critical section, i.e., blocking as little as possible each time. Thanks.

Comment: @2607: Then you have chosen the best solution. Fine grain locking in this case is very desirable.